# WPF binding backgrounds as SolidColorBrush

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have this grid:

```
    <Grid x:Name="topGrid"  Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
```

In my code if I set the background like this:

```
topGrid.Background = "#FF3C3C3C".ToBrush()
```

Using this extension:

```
Module Extensions
<Extension()>
Function ToBrush(ByVal HexColorString As String) As SolidColorBrush
    Return CType((New BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(HexColorString)), 
SolidColorBrush)
End Function
End Module
```

I can change background just fine, but i have around 20 grids on my form and i want to change backgrounds of all grids at once using bindings.

I have tried doing it like this:

This is xml:

```
 <Grid x:Name="topGrid" Background="{Binding MyBackgroundColor}" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0" >
```

This is code:

```
    Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button1.Click
    MyBackgroundColor = "#FF3C3C3C".ToBrush()
End Sub
Private _myBackgroundColor As SolidColorBrush
Public Property MyBackgroundColor() As SolidColorBrush
    Get
        Return _myBackgroundColor
    End Get
    Set
        _myBackgroundColor = Value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
End Sub
```

Comment: The property would have to fire the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. You may however not even need to use Bindings. DynamicResource should also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change all the backgrounds on many grids then a style is another way to go.
Although this is c# there's very little code and you could run it through an online converter.

I've done this in app.xaml for quickness but you'd want to put it in a resource dictionary merged in app.xaml in a proper app.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="gridBackgroundBrush" Color="Blue"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource gridBackgroundBrush}"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And you can change that brush:

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Color colour = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFD700");
        Application.Current.Resources["gridBackgroundBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush(colour);
    }
```

If you don't want one or two grids to have this behaviour you could just set their background to white or transparent and this will have precedence over the style.

If your requirement is instead more complicated then you could lose the style and instead use the resource directly as DynamicResource. Which might be what Clemens means.

```
 <Grid Background="{DynamicResource gridBackgroundBrush}"
```